# Three.js - STLLoader with cdn

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've decided to try to make a stl loader for fun. Now I'm mad.
I've tried everything on the internet and still not work, mostly from errors of cdn.
Right now I'm following the tutorial on Three.js site and [this one](https://medium.com/@atakandonmez/working-with-stl-files-on-three-js-faf94988493b).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>STL</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.154.0/build/three.module.js",
          "stl-loader": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stl-loader@1.0.0/STLLoader.min.js",
          "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/"
        }
      }
    </script>
        <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from 'three';
      import { STLLoader } from 'stl-loader';

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

      scene.background = new THREE.Color('#cc0000');

            const loadObject = () => {
        const loader = new STLLoader()
        loader.load("stl_file.stl", function (geometry) {
            group = new THREE.Group()
            scene.add(group)

            const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 })
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
            mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0)
            mesh.scale.set(10, 10, 10)
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true

            geometry.center()
            group.add(mesh)
        })
      } 

      loadObject();
            camera.position.z = 5;

      renderer.render( scene, camera );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Most of the code came from [here](https://medium.com/@atakandonmez/working-with-stl-files-on-three-js-faf94988493b) as I mentioned earlier.
From console
`Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'stl-loader' does not provide an export named 'STLLoader'`
but I know that it's not the only problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `STLLoader.min.js` is no ES6 module so you can't import it via ES6 import syntax. The file should have the same structure like the `STLLoader` from the `three` npm package:

https://unpkg.com/three@0.154.0/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js